# Multiple Plotspaces or shifted axes/plots

Tags: ios, real-time, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm looking to incorporate 4 real time scatter-plots into a graph and it has been requested that they be separated (at least in pairs) to make it easier to pick out signals. Would it be less resource intensive to have multiple plotspaces on my graph, or shift a new set of axes and plots on the same plotspace? Is this still the case if I add 2-4 more scatter-plots (for 6-8 total)?

FYI, I'm currently using CorePlot 1.6 (haven't had time to make the jump to 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the plots are in the same graph, use multiple plot spaces. A plot space just defines a coordinate mapping between the data and the screen so it does't use any video memory or other system resources (just a small amount of memory for the plot space object itself). Each plot and axis are `CALayer` objects, so those will be the primary drivers of resource usage.